# /bin/bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8)

Tags: dockerfile

I'm receiving the error in the title and I'm not sure why. I'm trying to run a docker container in Unraid. The dockerfile code is down below if anyone would like to critique.

```
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
LANG=en_US.UTF-8 \
LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8 \
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 \
TERM=xterm \
TZ=:/etc/localtime \
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin \
GOBIN=/go/bin \
APP=/go/src/smugmug-backup

RUN sed -e "/deb-src/d" -i /etc/apt/sources.list \
&& apt-get update \
&& apt-get install --no-install-recommends --yes \
    ca-certificates \
&& apt-get clean \
&& rm -rf /.root/cache \
&& rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

Answer (score 28):

```sh
$ sudo apt install locales
$ sudo locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

In the last step you, would see a text based UI, select `en_US.UTF-8` by moving using up and down arrow and selecting via spacebar or typing its id, which is 159.

Comment: ID for `en_US.UTF-8` is 159 in the selection list

Comment: don't work :( ....

Comment: @Vitalicus what part doesn't work ! Are you using a Debian based Linux